# determine whether a generic type has a standard constructor

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, constructor

Let `T` be a generic type. I would like to do something like this:

```
T x = default(T);
if (T has standard constructor)
  x = new T();
```

Of course, one could restrict `T` to types having such a constructor, but I do not want ot exclude value types.

How can you do that?

Comment: how would restricting `T where T : new()` exclude value types?

Comment: misunderstanding the documentation I thought this would exlude value types. But you are entirely right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to use reflection:

```
ConstructorInfo ci = typeof(T).GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
if (ci != null)
    x = (T)ci.Invoke(null);
```

You can also use `Activator.CreateInstance<T>()`, but that will throw an exception if the constructor doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

*edit:*

The question states that

> Of course, one could restrict T to types having such a constructor, but I do not want 
>   not exclude value types.

Using the constraint shown below does not limit `T` to Reference types. If you need to support other constructors *for a different reason,* please update your question.

---

*(pre-edit: may not apply to question after all)*

You are looking for a [*`new` constraint*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd2w2ew5.aspx) (also referred to as a *parameter-less constructor constraint)*:

```
class YourClass<T> where T : new()
{
    public T doSomething()
    {
        return new T();
    }
}
```

`T` is definitely allowed to be a value type, for instance:

```
YourClass<char> c = new YourClass<char>();
char result = c.doSomething();
```

Comment: If the type doesn't have a default constructor it should return `default(T)` not be uncompilable, according to the OP.

Comment: Thanks for helping me understand that... I *do* hope the question will be edited to make that a lot clearer.

Comment: Seems pretty clear to me, *"Of course, one could restrict T to types having such a constructor, but I do not want to"*  Also look at the code.  It's clearly designed to do *something* when there is no default constructor.

Comment: the sentence sounds a lot different when you read it as a whole, including what comes *after* the text you quoted. Anyway, I edited my answer to account for my mistake.

Comment: Clearly the OP knows how to constrain a type to only have default constructors.  If that solved his problem he'd just use it.  Clearly he's looking for something beyond that.  That's what I got out of that quote.  He didn't properly explain *why* it won't work (although it's not hard to figure out) but he did still explain, just fine, *that* this won't work.